# Woocommerce | Product page seems differently on my 2 websites

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want a product page like this:

http://www.migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/urun/convenient-water-bottle/

**( I talk about the "related product" and "add to card" etc. stuffs )**

but it seems like this :

http://www.oneclick.deniz-tasarim.site/urun/convenient-water-bottle/

how can I fix it?

it made by woocommerce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On plugin page on wp-admin,there is a warning/notification that says
>   continue woocommerce installation/costimization.I clicked it, then a
>   few settings dissapeared on my screen.I clicked next and next buttons
>   then When I checked my product page, the settings came automatically.